# Pass Arguments to Class stored in Dictionary

Tags: c#

I would like to store a dictionary of derived objects (all from same base) along the lines of

```
Dictionary<Type,BaseClass> Dict = new Dictionary<Type,BaseClass>()
{
  {typeof(string), new Item1fromBaseClass()}
  {typeof(bool), new Item2fromBaseClass()}
  ...
};
```

I don't know how to pass this structure the arguments - the constructor necessarily looks like `Item1fromBaseClass = new Item1fromBaseClass(Type t, object o)` The good news is that the signature will be the same for every class. I have successfully tested with no parameters. Is this possible? What does the initializer for the dict look like?

**Edit to add:**
given a `BaseClass` object `i` in another class, I need to be able to

```
i = Dict[typeof(string)]; //Args?
//i is now an instance of Item1fromBaseClass(Type t,object o)
```

Comment: What's stopping you from writing `{typeof(string), new Item1fromBaseClass(typeof(string), new object())}` ?

Comment: In another class I have a `BaseClass` field. I need this to happen: `BaseClass i = Dict[typeof(string)];` at which point i takes its specific form. Where do the arguments go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<Type, object, BaseClass>> Dict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Type, object, BaseClass>>()
{
    { typeof(string), (t, o) => new Item1fromBaseClass(t, o) },
    { typeof(bool), (t, o) => new Item2fromBaseClass(t, o) },
};
```

Then you can write:

```
i = Dict[typeof(string)].Invoke(type, obj);
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Couldn't have guessed a search term to arrive at this. What is this called?

Comment: There are a few names for things in here, but in essence this is "factory repository" or a form of "inversion of control container".

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this question is not very clear. However, it sounds like the issue you are having is that you need to retrieve the `BaseClass` value at some later point in time, and the `object o` parameter to the constructor is not known until that time.

If so, then you will need to defer construction of the `BaseClass` object until that time. After all, otherwise how would you know what the `o` value is?

That would look something like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<object, BaseClass>> Dict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, BaseClass>>()
{
  {typeof(string), o => new Item1fromBaseClass(typeof(string), o) },
  {typeof(bool), o => new Item2fromBaseClass(typeof(bool), o) },
  ...
};
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
// The object parameter for the constructor
object o = ...;

i = Dict[typeof(string)](o);
```

If that does not address your question, please improve the question so that it is more clear. Provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you are trying to do. State in *precise* terms what that code does now, and what you would like for it to do instead.